# Aliasing Querystring Params in BeginForm with FormMethod.Get - MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

### The Question

Is there a way to alias the parameters generated by MVC, in my case it would be the `searchTerm` param?  For example, in my viewmodel it would still be SearchViewModel.searchTerm but the URL would look more like `/Home/Search?s=jimmy`

### Search Form

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) {%>
       <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.searchTerm) %>
       <input type="submit" value="Search" />
<% } %>
```

### View Model

```
    public class SearchViewModel
    {
        public string searchTerm { get; set; }
    }
```

### The URL Generated

```
/Home/Search?searchTerm=jimmy
```

Edit: Doesn't seem possible.  Looks like I'll have to do it on my own..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could either change your textbox control to not use templating and use the name your want to see in the query string like this...

```
<%= Html.TextBox("s", Model.searchTerm)
```

Or you could change the template that the TextBoxFor method uses with a own custom one, but I'm not sure what convention you would use.  Maybe check for modelnames of "searchTerm"?

[This site](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) has some examples of how to create a custom template.

Sorry, if the syntax was not correct in the code, but I do not have MVC on this machine.